# How can I change input value in Vue when value is set and update it when it is object of arrays?

Tags: vue.js

I generate so many input boxes on loop of article array.
article is array of objects. Input boxes values are set with "value" key in each object.

```
<div
  v-for="(option, i) in this.article"
  :key="i"
  class="form-row"
  >
     <div class="col">
        <input
           v-model="option.value"
           :label="'label '+i"
           :name="'inputValue'+i"
           type="text"
           required
         />
      </div>
      

</div>
<button @click="submit"></button>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Article',
    data(){
      return(
        article:[
         {id: 'art1', value: 'artValue1'},
         {id: 'art2', value: 'artValue2'},
         {id: 'art3', value: 'artValue3'}
         // There are about 50 objects
        ]
      )
    },
    methods:{
        submit(){
        // How get values of inputs?
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I make the value of input change and update the object in vue?

Comment: You don't need 'this' with 'article'.  Use ```v-for="(option, i) in article"```.  Also, I'm pretty sure that ```<input>``` tags do not have a 'label' attribute.

Comment: @Tim Label is not the problem. Ignore it please. I need a way like 'serialize' but don't know how to implement in vue

Comment: I saw that you posted a new Vue question today.  Have you looked at my answer on this question?  I think it solves this problem.

Comment: Yes and I voted you in here. But in that question when I use computed it worked. At first I haven't been using it.

Comment: I appreciate the upvote.  I guess my point is, if my solution answers this question, then please accept the answer.  But if it doesn't, then no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample Single File Component based on your code.  Look at my modifications.  The 'magic' of Vue reactivity is that the 'article' data is updated in real time as you change the input values.

```
<template>
  <div class="input-bound-object-array">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
          <div class="form-group" v-for="(option, i) in article" :key="i">
            <label>{{ option.id }}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="option.value"
              required />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        article: [
          { id: 'art1', value: 'artValue1' },
          { id: 'art2', value: 'artValue2' },
          { id: 'art3', value: 'artValue3' }
          // There are about 50 objects
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submitForm() {
        // 'this.article' is updated as the input values are changed, so at this point
        // you have the data changes, so you can process it as needed, i.e. POST to REST endpoint
        console.log(this.article);
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return the `object` from `data` function and you can pass `option` to `submit` handler and print the input values.

> // How get values of inputs? -> Do you mean all of the inputs or input where ever the button clicked or anything else. Below code is to handle individual input and submit handlers

```
<template>
<div
  v-for="(option, i) in article"
  :key="i"
  class="form-row"
  >
     <div class="col">
        <input
           v-model="option.value"
           :label="'label ' + i"
           :name="'inputValue' + i"
           type="text"
           required
         />
      </div>
      <!-- <button @click="submit(option)">Submit</button> to handle individual inputs -->

</div>
<!-- <button @click="submitAll()">Submit All</button> to handle all inputs -->

</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Article',
    data() {
    return { // you missed this
      article:[
        {id: 'art1', value: 'artValue1'},
        {id: 'art2', value: 'artValue2'},
        {id: 'art3', value: 'artValue3'}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit(option) { // current option
     console.log(option.id, option.value)
    },
   submitAll() {
     console.log(this.article) // which will have update input values as 
    you're using `v-model`, check `values`
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

Demo Link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-zqrk3n)

Comment: Thanks for your comment which I missed return. I edited But I think you didn't get my real problem. I need to get the value of 50 inputs. How can I get it?

Comment: You can use `this.article`, console.log(this.article) // which will have updated input values as you're using `v-model`